# Change image background by R

Tags: r, image, matrix, raster

How can I use R to change the green background to yellow without changing black “A”?

[image]

Comment: You need to provide more detail than this. For example what code and data did you use to produce this plot?

Comment: I have a png file. I wanna change part of its background and save to a new png. Thanks

Comment: please edit your question to include this information ...

Answer (score 0):

```
library(grid) 
 m<-readPNG("1.png")
 y <- rgb(m[,,1], m[,,2], m[,,3])
 dim(y) <- dim(m)[1:2]
 y[y=="#008C46"]<-"#FFFF00"
 grid.raster(y, interpolate=FALSE)
```

I just did it by this way. But it looks like there is sawtooth on letter now. 
How can I improve it?Thanks.

[image]